# Karbonn A18 not getting detected in Eclipse for Debugging

Tags: android, debugging, usb, driver

I know there are already many threads on this topic but my question is little different. I'm currently using Karbonn A18 android phone having Ice cream sandwidth installed on it. So far I've created apps with the help of emulator but y'day I tried to attach my device with eclipse for development purpose but somehow, despite of following all the steps, it's not being detected in the eclipse.

1. I've checked that my device has Google USB drivers installed. I confirmed this by going to MyComputer->Manage->Devices->Karbonn A18 then right click and update the usb drivers
2. I've clicked the USB debugging option when I connect my phone to the system USB driver

But when I go to the Windows->Others->Device view on my eclipse, I see blank page. 
Moreover I'm not prompted that any device has been attached for debugging either.

Can you please suggest how to find the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select connect as "Media Device" in USB computer connection.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the driver isn't installed.

- Go to Device Manager from Control Panel.

Now if there are some driver under Android Phone, then other setting might have caused that. Else, if your Android show small yellow mark, there is problem with the driver.

- Right Click on that 'android' button
- click Update driver and chose latest driver from computer.

That should work. If you have bought new phone, like Karbonn, and you are tried of searching adb driver online, like I was, its actually on your own phone. Navigate to SD-Card on your phone and copy 'Pcdriver' to your desktop. Unzip it and update your driver selecting. Hope this helps.

If you on Windows 8, you may have to Disable Driver Signing before that:

1. Move your mouse pointer to the upper right-hand side of your
   monitor. This will open the charm bar.
2. Click the Settings charm.
3. Click the Change PC settings link at the bottom of the Settings
   menu.
4. Click the Restart now button.
5. Click Troubleshoot.
6. Click Advanced Options.
7. Click the Startup Settings.
8. Click the Restart button. Your computer will reboot.
9. After the reboot, press the [F7] key. This chooses the 7) Disable
   driver signature enforcement option.
10. Login to Windows 8.